# B2C: Audience claim is formatted differently when using a client credential vs authorization flow

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I'm getting the same value but s differently formatted `aud` claim of my JWT when using `client_credential` and `authorization_code` grant types when using the same client id and requested scope using B2C User flows.

###### Interactive Auth Code Flow

```
POST /tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_app_SignIn/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e392d8bc-8766-4d7b-bac5-32a5716a8600
Host: tenant.b2clogin.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1120
 
grant_type=authorization_code&code=<code>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.pstmn.io%2Fv1%2Fcallback&code_verifier=<verifier>&client_id=<clientid>
```

Response:

```
{"access_token":"<jwt>","token_type":"Bearer",
"not_before":1706064107,"expires_in":3600,
"expires_on":1706067707,"resource":"<resource>","profile_info":"<profile>",
"scope":"https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/177da752-d895-4325-9aee-d6e459bee811/app.full_access",
"refresh_token":"<refresh token>","refresh_token_expires_in":86400}
```

###### Decoded JWT value:

`"aud": "177da752-d895-4325-8aee-d6e459bee811"`

###### Non-Interactive Client Credentials Flow

```
POST /tenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_app_signin/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.1
Accept: */*
Host: tenant.b2clogin.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 231
 
client_id=<clientid>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Ftenant.onmicrosoft.com%2F177da752-d895-4325-9aee-d6e459bee811%2F.default&client_secret=<secret>&grant_type=client_credentials
```

response:

```
{"access_token":"<jwt>","token_type":"Bearer","not_before":1706057659,"expires_in":3600,"expires_on":1706061259,"resource":"https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/177da752-d895-4325-9aee-d6e459bee811"}
```

###### Decoded JWT Value

`"aud": "https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/177da752-d895-4325-8aee-d6e459bee811"`

Is this by design?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tested both interactive and client credentials and the `aud` claim comes back as expected - a GUID to the application the token is intended for. Are you passing the correct scopes in the client credentials flow? Can you include the body of both requests (exclude/obscure  PII).

Comment: Updated with additional request details

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Client credentials have the context of an application, while code grant has the context of a user.

Comment: Is there documentation that explains this difference?

Comment: Although this answer is technically accurate, it is not answering what was asked by the OP, which is the discrepancy in the `aud` claim. The audience should always be the application GUID the token is intended for (in the case of Azure AD B2C JWTs).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some confusion between the `aud` and `sub` JWT claims in the example you provided.

In your case, since you are using the same client ID and (assuming) you are targeting the same resource in both the authorization code and the client credentials flows, you would expect the `aud` claim to be identical in both tokens. The different values you are seeing are unusual. It might be due to some misconfiguration or how the token endpoint is implemented, maybe ask the provider for clarification? remember, the `aud` claim is about the **where** the token is going, not **who** is using it. the 'who' part is represented by the `sub` claim. this is explained in [RFC 7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.3).

So, long story short: if the client is meant to access "api.my-domain.com", then this should always be the `aud` value in your JWT, regardless of whether it's obtained through the Interactive Auth Code or the Non-Interactive Client Credentials flow.